# Error in Httpresponse

Tags: android

The following is an `HttpResponse`:

```
Result:{"basicDetailsList":[{"imageUrl":"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"}],"response":"success"}
```

I'm using the following code,

```
 JSONObject objResponse=new JSONObject(retResult);
 final String strResponse=objResponse.getString("response");
 if(strResponse!=null && strResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
     //it get inside the loop-->
     final String image=objResponse.getString("imageUrl");
 }
```

The imageUrl is a Base64encoded string.

I'm getting the following error:

`org.json.JSONException: No value for imageUrl`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting the serialize image as JSON  response and then trying to save it as an image. is it ok to you?

Comment: Your parsing is wrong, first of all get JsonArray of "basicDetailsList" in that JsonArray you will get your value.

Comment: You should use UIL or Volley to get image from url

Comment: When your parsing is wrong, I don't think it would get into the if condition that you mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a json array. You skip it. I think it should be like this:

```
JSONObject objResponse=new JSONObject(retResult);
JSONArray basicDetailsList = objResponse.getJSONArray("basicDetailsList");
JSONObject actualObject = basicDetailsList[0];
String response = actualObject.getString("response");

if(response.equals("success"))
    String imageURL= actualObject.getString("imageUrl");
```

I didn't try this code. There can be typo.

Answer (score 0):

USe this way:

```
JSONObject objResponse=new JSONObject(retResult);
JSONArray basicDetailsList = objResponse.getJSONArray("basicDetailsList");
for(int i = 0; i < basicDetailsList .length(); i++ ){
   JSONObject c = datas.getJSONObject(i);
   String imageURL= c.getString("imageUrl");

}
```